# How to send ack from android app to server through xmpp gcm

Tags: xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending a notification to android app using `xmpp gcm`.
When the server sends the notification request to `gcm` I receive `ack` from `ccs` that it has receive a notification request. This notification is send by `gcm` using `xmpp protocol` to my app. I want the app to send an `ack` to my server that it has receved the notification.

Can any one tel me how to send ack through `gcm xmpp protocol` to the server?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do this is to follow https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html , and read "Send a message" section. The sent message will be read by our xmpp gcm server, consume the message there.